# TIBCO EMS ActiveDatabase _ADB.DUPDETECT

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems

I trying create one topic publisher with TIBCO Designer using a ActiveDatabase Adapter.
But every time when the adapter starts one topic named _ADB.DUPDETECT is created too

The problem is: **my EMS server don´t allow dynamic topics**. Then I get following error:

```
2010 Aug 23 10:38:20:825 GMT -3 M2M.M2M Error [Adapter] AEADB-910005
Startup Error. SDK Exception Code = AESDKC-0151, Category = JmsComm, Severity = errorRole, Description = JMS Error: Failed to create Jms Subscriber DupDetectMessage : Invalid destination, File = C:/suren/workspace/Maverick/maverick-5.6.1-dev/libmaverick/MJmsConsumer.cpp, line = 271 received on starting the adapter after initialization. The Repository URL is D:\Temp\Lixo\AT_adadb_9991.dat and the Configuration URL is M2M.
```

Unfortunately couldn´t find any information about this error in Google or in TIBCOmmunity.

Anybody can help me with this?
Thanks advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create the `_ADB.DUPDETECT` topic in EMS before you start the adapter. e.g., from within `tibemsadmin`

```
create topic _ADB.DUPDETECT
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow your TIBCO EMS Server the creation of dynamic topics you need to create one like this by using the EMS Administration Tool:

```
connect tcp://localhost:7222
Login name (admin): admin
Password:
Connected to: tcp://localhost.7222
tcp://localhost:7222> create topic >
Topic '>' has been created
```

You can do this via TIBCO Administrator too:

[image]